# Apps Script Exception: Document xxx is missing - how to make it re-run

Tags: google-apps-script, error-handling

I have been struggling with this one for a bit. I get that triggers are not always reliable, document is busy, ect. I am trying to figure out how to re-run the process if there is an error. The script is pulling select data from 12 sheets and dropping it into a single sheet hourly. In the script I have defined the sheets and tabs, then repeat this 12 times. The trigger for it is simply:

```
function myFunction() {
  exportDashdata();
}
```

**A snippet of the code running is:**

```
const frawData1 = testSheet.getRange("B:Q").getValues().map(([b,c,d,e,f,,,i,,,,,,,,q]) => [b,c,d,e,f,i,q]);
  
  var data = []
   for (var i = 0; i< frawData1.length ; i++){
    if(frawData1[i][0] !== "")            
     { 
      data.push(frawData1[i])
   }
   }
  
  var copyData = targetssSheet.getRange(targetssSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

Comment: put the trunk of codes into try catch statement , catch error, if error is "The error you predefined"  inside the catch statement , call function again.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
const data = testSheet.getRange("B1:Q" + testSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().map(([b, c, d, e, f, , , i, , , , , , , , q]) => [b, c, d, e, f, i, q]);
var copyData = targetssSheet.getRange(targetssSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

Using indeterminate ranges like that leads to a lot of unnecessary nulls.